# Cloudant and Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, cloudant

I have a question regarding the possibility to configure Cloudant with Elasticsearch.

I have a Cloudant service on Bluemix with some documents uploaded and I'm wondering if I can configure Elasticsearch in some way.

The problem is that my boss want to use Kibana as visualization tool starting with log data loaded into Cloudant.

Thank for any helps and tips.

Answer (score 0):

i have not tried it, but given that Cloudant and CouchDB are similar it may be possible with this logstash plugin:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-couchdb_changes.html